# How to make a checkbox clickable which is inside a button?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(".raw_data").click(function () {
   $("[name='raw_data']").prop("checked",!$("[name='raw_data']").is(':checked')).change();
});
```

```html
<button class="raw_data" type="button">
    <input type="checkbox" name="raw_data">
        raw_data
</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

As you see, when I click the button, the checkbox works well, but when I click the checkbox itself, it sucks...

So, how to make a checkbox clickable which is inside a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply your `.prop('checked')` only when you click inside the button but outside the checkbox.

You can do that by checking `e.target` : `if(!$(e.target).is('input'))`.

Also, you don't need that `.change()` at the end.

```js
$(".raw_data").click(function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).is('input')) $("[name='raw_data']").prop("checked", !$("[name='raw_data']").is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<button class="raw_data" type="button">
  <input type="checkbox" name="raw_data">
  raw_data
</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to toggle checkbox on button click:

```js
        $(".raw_data, .raw_data > input").click(function () {
            var input = $(this).find("input").length ? $(this).find("input") : $(this)
            input.prop("checked", !input.prop("checked"));
        });
```

```html
            <button class="raw_data" type="button">
                <input type="checkbox" name="raw_data">
                raw_data
            </button>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```